# disable a button based on logged in users credentials.

Tags: php

I have a page that is access by several users. Each person logs in and a PHP page looks up the user and verifies the person. This can also pull of information about the users grade. I would like to disable the attached search button if the grade equal 1a or 1b, anyone else is OK. I have other javascript disable a DIV but i can't get it to work here.

```
    <div id="footer" style="background-color:#3399cc;clear:both;text-align:center;"><font  color="#000099">DJR</font>
    <a href="change.php"class="buttons">Change password</a>
    <a href="out.php" class="buttons">Logout</a>
    <a href="search.php" class="buttons">Search</a>
    <a href="Calendar.php" class="buttons">Calendar</a>
    <a href="AL.php" class="buttons">Leave</a>
    </div>
```

This is how I get information regarding the current user!

```
  $fgmembersite->userID();
```

if this equals anything but 1a and 1b then its enabled. Thanks in advance again, always great help on this site.

Comment: PHP runs on the *server*. If you want to disable the button on the *client*, you'll need to use something other than PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to show disabled buttons to users? Just echo the ones they can use.

```
<?php 
  if(($fgmembersite->userID() == '1a') || ($fgmembersite->userID() == '1b')){
    echo '
      //echo buttons allowed to 1a and 1b users (or nothing at all)
    ';
  }
    else{
      echo '
        //echo buttons not allowed to 1a and 1b users (or nothing at all)
      ';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<?php
    <a href="search.php" class="buttons"<?php if( $fgmembersite->userID()<>'1a' or  $fgmembersite->userID()<>'1b'  ){
echo " disabled='disabled' ";
}?>>Search</a>
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure about this condition `if( !$fgmembersite->userID())`

Answer (score 0):

Below pseudo code may help you

```
<a href="search.php" class="buttons" <?php if(//users grade is 1a or 1b) { ?> onClick="return false;" <?php } ?> >Search</a>
```